# REST requests to an API falls in timeout randomly

Tags: tcp, wireshark

0

I developed a web app that communicate with an external API in REST. Most of the time I have no problem, but a few times (1 or 2 times a day) I have my request which is timed out although the message I send is correct.

By analyzing with Wireshark, here is the error I get when a request is timed out : [TCP Retransmission][TCP Port numbers reused]

There's an error to upload an image, so you'll find the screenshot of Wireshark here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGgpx.jpg

The problem occurs on several of my client workstations with different public IP addresses. The API itself has the same IP address.

Can you help me please ?

Comment: What does the capture on the server show?

Comment: This could be anything. Your client, your network cable, your OS, your router, your ISP, their ISP, their router, their os, their network cable, their server, their software, their DB, etc. It could be a microwave interfering with some electronics in the wall. It is literally impossible for us to solve with your data. Try anything to find out it is not you and the work your way closer to the external API. Maybe you can find something on the way.